# (kal) calendar/tableview view hierarchy broken in tabbar

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uistoryboard

I'm using [Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal) and am having trouble getting it to display properly.

Right now, in the Storyboard, I have a subview of the main view with the tag 1:

[image: view-hierarchy]

I have that subview fitted to the space between the navbar and tabbar:

[image]

The problem is that the calendar/tableview (Kal) is not appearing properly in that subview:

[image]

First there is that small grey bar above the month (maybe Kal's spacing for the iPhone's info bar?). Then the tableview at the bottom of the calendar is behaving as if it extends far below the tab bar.  That is, the cells won't scroll properly, as can be seen by the cell labeled 11:58 which is peeking up from the bottom. (I have scrolled it as far as it will go.)

Here is where I'm setting the delegates and loading the view for the Kal calendar/tableview:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad 
{    
    NSLog(@"DateTimeViewController - viewDidLoad");

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.calendar = [[KalViewController alloc] init];

    self.calendar.delegate = self;
    self.calendar.dataSource = self;

    [[self.view viewWithTag:1] addSubview:self.calendar.view];

    NSLog(@"selected date = %@",self.calendar.selectedDate);

}
```

Comment: why dont you try to set a frame for the subview?

Comment: @Sharanya - Hmm...That's not what I did as shown in the 2nd picture? Maybe I'm not familiar with that.  What's a frame/how do I do it?

Comment: you can set a view frame for any view/subview you create. check the answer

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, I went to `KalViewController.m` in `loadView`

and changed the code in this way:

```
//  KalView *kalView = [[KalView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] delegate:self logic:logic];
int width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width;
int height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height-93;
KalView *kalView = [[KalView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height) delegate:self logic:logic];
```

This solved me both the problem of the "header" margin and the table view size.
Just play with the height value.

Answer (score 0):

Play around a little bit with your 'y' value in CGRectMake to get a required frame. try this

```
KalViewController *kalView = [[KalViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,-20,100,320)];
self.calender = kalView;
```

CGRectMake(<*x position*> , <*y position*> , <*required height*> , <*required width*>)

Comment: Looks like KalViewController doesn't respond to initWithFrame.

Comment: does it have a view property??

Comment: just do an init.. and then try to add a frame with kalView.view.frame.size.y = -20; or something similar... check its properties

Comment: Interesting.  It does have a view property.  Changing the view's frame is causing some strange behavior.  I'm going to keep trying different numbers.

Comment: Now it's not receiving touch input properly.  I'm getting the sense that it is drawing one frame but responding to touches in another frame.